# powershell convert objectsid to sid

Tags: powershell

Hallo. If I run this code

```
$server = "."
$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$server" 
$adsi.psbase.children | where {$_.schemaClassName -match "user"} | select name, objectsid |Format-Table -auto
```

I get object sid in this form

1 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 21 0 0 0 138 93 63 151 163 49 215 2 60 164 164 50 236 3 0 0

I'd like to know if it's possible to convert it to get the same result that you have from win32_useraccount class. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$adsi.psbase.children | where {$_.schemaClassName -match "user"} | foreach-object{    
  $account = New-Object Security.Principal.NTAccount $_.name
  $account.Translate( [Security.Principal.Securityidentifier] ).Value
}
```

Comment: Hi Shay. Thank you very much. I was looking for a way to find the name of admin account.                                        $server = "."
$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$server" 
$admin = $adsi.psbase.children | where {$_.schemaClassName -match "user"} | % {    
  $account = New-Object Security.Principal.NTAccount $_.name
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        name = $_.Name
        sid = $account.translate( [Security.Principal.Securityidentifier] ).Value 
        } | ? {$_.sid.endswith('-500')} | % {$_.name}

} 
$admin

Comment: As soon as I'll reach the minimum score necessary I'll vote you. Thanks again.

Comment: bind to the administrator account and get its name. In powershell v1 you may have to add psbase first ($admin.psbase.name)

$admin = [adsi]"WinNT:///$server/administrator,user"
$admin.name

Comment: With the following one-liner you can get the name and sid of the admin account:  

$admin | select @{n='Name';e={$_.Name}}, @{n='SID';e={(New-Object Security.Principal.NTAccount $_.name).translate( [Security.Principal.Securityidentifier] ).Value }}

Comment: Thanks again Shay and congratulations for your blog that is really interesting ;)

Comment: This still doesn't convert an objectsid to a sid. That's what the title of this item is asking for. That's what I need to do. :-(

Answer (score 2):

While in most circumstances [Shay Levy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3751094/11649702) will work, the literal answer to the question of translating a `Byte[]`-style SID to a `string`-style SID would be:

```
$adsi.psbase.children | Where-Object {$_.schemaClassName -eq "User"} | Foreach-Object {
    [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new($_.objectSid.value, 0).Value
}
```